# Asp.net website custom logins

Tags: asp.net

i have made a simple web application which uses a table from a database to show the data also for the logins i used asp.net membership provider. which made the aspnet.mdf database. Now i don't want to use 2 databases for this. I just want a single database which also contains the users and roles. Can any one give me an advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

[How to Configure ASP.Net Membership Providers to Use Our Own Database?](http://codes.codedigest.com/FAQ/16-How-to-Configure-ASP-Net-Membership-Providers-to-Use-Our-Own-Database-.aspx)

If, on the other hand, you wish to use your own database structure, you will have to create a custom Membership Provider. It's quite a long process, but not very complicated.

Here's a good explanation: about [Creating a custom membership provider](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/780/creating-a-custom-membership-provider/)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want to create two databases. You can use [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) to create membership tables to your existing database.